# AngularJS - Invalid Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I'm using this RegEx to validate the password entered. The password needs to have at least 1 capital alphabet, 1 number and 1 symbol:

```
/(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z\d])/
```

I'm using the RegEx along with `ng-pattern` in an `type="password"` input. It works fine when entered `Mike123@` or `Mike123*`. But it throws the following error when entering `Mike123***`:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^Mik123***$/: Nothing to repeat
```

The RegEx works fine here: https://regex101.com/r/j0O4aw/1. Code where it's being used:

```
<div class="input_fieldholder">
  <input type="password"
  class="m-b-0 login_typefield"
  placeholder="Password"
  name="password"
  ng-class="{ form_error: vm.formObject.password.$dirty && vm.formObject.password.$invalid }"
  ng-model="vm.password"
  ng-minlength="6"
  ng-change="vm.onChangePassword()"
  ng-pattern="/(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z\d])/"
  required
  ng-attr-autofocus="{{ vm.autoFocus }}">

  <div class="text-left m-t-3">
    <div ng-show="vm.formObject.password.$dirty && vm.formObject.password.$error.required" class="text-danger">{{ 'PASSWORD_REQUIRED_VALIDATION' | translate }}</div>
    <div ng-show="vm.formObject.password.$dirty && vm.formObject.password.$error.minlength" class="text-danger">{{ 'PASSWORD_LENGTH_VALIDATION' | translate }}</div>
    <div ng-show="vm.formObject.password.$dirty && vm.formObject.password.$error.pattern" class="text-danger">{{ 'PASSWORD_PATTERN_VALIDATION' | translate }}</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="input_fieldholder">
  <input type="password"
  class="m-t-10 m-b-0 login_typefield"
  placeholder="Confirm Password"
  name="confirmPassword"
  ng-class="{ form_error: vm.formObject.confirmPassword.$dirty && vm.formObject.confirmPassword.$invalid }"
  ng-model="vm.confirmPassword"
  ng-pattern="vm.password"
  ng-change="vm.onChangePassword()"
  required
  compare-field-selector="[name='password']">
  <div class="text-left m-t-3">
    <span ng-show="vm.formObject.confirmPassword.$dirty && vm.formObject.confirmPassword.$invalid" class="text-danger">{{'PASSWORD_CONFIRM_VALIDATION' | translate }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How should I resolve this?

Comment: You are certainly inverting the pattern and the string to search in.

Comment: @GaétanRYCKEBOER is right! The error you get really shows that the password entered is indeed treated as the regex to match against... I do not know angular... Is ng-pattern coming from the framework or are you using that in your onChangePassword()? For the later, you need to show us the code so we can pin point the problem.

Comment: `ng-pattern="vm.password"`, this was the issue in the confirmPassword input field. It was not necessary and removing it worked. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

From the example.

The “`id=regex`” contains the regex to match.
The “`id=input`” contains the string to check against the regex.

```
<script>
  angular.module('ngPatternExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.regex = '\\d+';
  }]);
</script>
```

followed by :

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
 <form name="form">
  <label for="regex">Set a pattern (regex string): </label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="regex" id="regex" />
  <br>
  <label for="input">This input is restricted by the current pattern: 
  </label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="model" id="input" name="input" ng-pattern="regex" /><br>
  <hr>
  input valid? = <code>{{form.input.$valid}}</code><br>
  model = <code>{{model}}</code> 
 </form>
</div>
```